# Starting threads in a for cycle produces multiple results

Tags: python, python-2.7

-**I found the problem!**- In function SendMessage I was using UserID (with capital letters) instead of userid (which was the actual parameter passed to each thread). So Python printed the UserID of the for cycle instead of the "individual" userid passed to the different functions. It was only a logging problem, the program sent messages correctly.

I have a **for** that loops through the elements of a user's list. Each iteration, I would like to start a separate background thread to send a message to that user. By saying "send a message" I mean a simple POST request made using the *requests* Python lib. At the end of the thread, an output on the console is written. Every 24 requests (so every 24 threads) the app needs to stop for about a second.

```py
Success = 0
Bounces = 0

def SendMessage(botid, token, userid, messageid, tag):
    global Success
    global Bounces
    try:
        payload = {...}
        r = requests.post("...", params=payload, headers=head, timeout=2)
        #problem with request?
        pjson = json.loads(r.text)

        if r.status_code != 200:

            log(str(r.status_code) + " " + pjson["result"] + " UserID: " + UserID + "; URL: " + "..." + BotID + "/users/" + UserID + "/send; Params: " + str(payload))
            Bounces += 1
            return

        Success += 1

        return

    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        #wait for connection to be available again!
        while not conn_available():
            print("... Waiting for a new connection...")
            time.sleep(10)
        log("Request timed out. UserID: " + UserID + "; URL: " + "..." + BotID + "/users/" + UserID + "/send; Params: " + str(payload))
        Bounces += 1
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        log("Unable to connect. UserID: " + UserID + "; URL: " + "..." + BotID + "/users/" + UserID + "/send; Params: " + str(payload))
        Bounces += 1
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        log("Invalid request. UserID: " + UserID + "; URL: " + "..." + BotID + "/users/" + UserID + "/send; Params: " + str(payload))
        Bounces += 1
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        log("Invalid request. UserID: " + UserID + "; URL: " + "..." + BotID + "/users/" + UserID + "/send; Params: " + str(payload))
        Bounces += 1

while True:
    newMsgsReq = ""
    try:
        #Check for new messages
        newMsgsReq = requests.get("...", timeout=2)

        if newMsgsReq.text == "false":
            #exit sub
            time.sleep(2)
            continue

    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        log("Request has failed: There was an error in the request: [" + str(errh) + "]")
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        log("Request has failed: check internet connection & retry: [" + str(errc) + "]")
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        log("Request has failed: check internet connection & retry: [" + str(errt) + "]")
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        log("Request has failed: There was an error in the request: [" + str(err) + "]")
        time.sleep(2)
        continue

    #we have a message!!!
    #Extract BotID, Token, MessageID
    msgInf = newMsgsReq.text.split("|")
    MessageID = msgInf[0]
    BotID = msgInf[1]
    Token = msgInf[2]
    Tag = msgInf[3]
    del msgInf[0:4]
    suc("New message found: " + str(MessageID))
    suc("Total recipients: " + str(len(msgInf)))
    #Begin send!
    Cycles = 0
    TotCycles = 0
    #Loop through msgInf
    for UserID in msgInf:

        #Create the thread.
        process = threading.Thread(target=SendMessage, args=[BotID, Token, UserID, MessageID, Tag])
        process.start()

        TotCycles += 1
        pb.print_progress_bar(TotCycles)
        Cycles += 1
        if Cycles == 24:

            time.sleep(1)
            Cycles = 0

    suc("Message " + str(MessageID) + " sent successfully (" + str(Success) + " success, " + str(Bounces) + " bounces")
    Success = 0
    Bounces = 0
    time.sleep(3)
```

Let's say my user list is: 
{1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 24, 25, ...}. I expect my application to output:
1. Message **1** sent successfully...
2. Message **2** sent successfully...
...
24. Message **24** sent successfully.
Instead, I am getting this output:
1. Message **1** sent successfully.
2. Message **1** sent successfully.
...
24. Message **1** sent successfully.
So all the 24 outputs are related to the first of the 24 ids. It seems like the for loop does not proceed...

Comment: Did you try tracing your code execution with the step debugger ? Or just adding usable debug traces at the right places ? Like printing the value of `msgInf` - so you know which messageId etc is being handled in each iteration of your while loop - and printing each UserId in the inner for loop so you can check what's going on here ?

Comment: **I found the problem**! In function _SendMessage_ I was using _UserID_ (with capital letters) instead of _userid_ (which was the actual parameter passed to each thread). So Python printed the _UserID_ of the for cycle instead of the "individual" _userid_ passed to the different functions. It was only a logging problem, the program sent messages correctly.

Comment: Uhu... That's what you get for having application code at the top level. If your main loop was - as it should - encapsulated in a  `main` function, `UserID` wouldn't have been a global, and you would have got a nice `NameError` immediatly instead.  For those who still wonder why globals are evils...

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The `NameError` would probably have helped me a lot not wasting hours and hours trying to figure out where the problem was...

Answer (score 0):

This prints the incremented counter without any trouble so I think you may need to provide all of the code and some sample input.

```
import threading
import time

def SendMessage(userid):
    print(userid)

while True:
    cycles = 1
    for user_id in [1, 2, 3]:

        process = threading.Thread(target=SendMessage, args=[user_id])
        process.start()

        cycles += 1
        if cycles == 24:
            time.sleep(1)
            cycles = 0

    time.sleep(3)
```

[Run it on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/GainsboroMediumClass)